# How to display the result of a php submit form in a jquery dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-dialog

i have a problem, i have a form with a single input and  submit button called "search" in a jquery dialog box. I want to display the mySQL data when clicking on this button in another jquery dialog box . How can i do that ?

Comment: Use jquery ajax to submit the form and get the mysql data back and put this data in dialog and show the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#search', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getMysqlData.php',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#otherDialogBox").html(data);
            $("#otherDialogBox").dialog();
        }
    });
});
```